Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to server closed
Есть необходимость вывода информации о времени перезагрузки сервера, 2х последних установленных обновлениях.
Команда #1 вида:
# ansible all -m shell -a "echo Перезагружен: ; uptime -s | xargs -I{} date -d {} '+%T %d.%m.%Y' ; echo 2 последних установленных обновления: ; echo -------------------------------------------------------------" -i /home/user/test.ini -b -K --become-user 'root'

Отрабатывает успешно на обоих серверах:
server1 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
Перезагружен:
11:16:17 05.04.2024
2 последних установленных обновления:
-------------------------------------------------------------
server2 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
Перезагружен:
16:13:37 11.04.2024
2 последних установленных обновления:

Команда #2 вида:
# ansible all -m shell -a "echo Перезагружен: ; uptime -s | xargs -I{} date -d {} '+%T %d.%m.%Y' ; echo 2 последних установленных обновления: ; rpm -qa -last | head -n2 ; echo -------------------------------------------------------------" -i /home/user/ANSIBLE/hosts/test.ini -b -K --become-user 'root'

Выполняется для server1, но не выполняется для server2:
server1 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
Перезагружен:
11:16:17 05.04.2024
2 последних установленных обновления:
ncdu-1.17-alt1.x86_64                         Mon 25 Mar 2024 09:36:44 PM +05
kesl-12.0.0-6672.x86_64                       Fri 22 Mar 2024 10:50:40 AM +05
server2 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to server2 closed.",
    "unreachable": true
}

Подскажите, с чем может быть связана проблема?
Команда #rpm -qa -last | head -n2, запущенная на server2 отрабатывает успешно.
